# How do I retrieve DataColumn.DefaultValue from a Sql Table?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Is there a way to determine a column's defaultvalue from the Sql Database using ado.net?

I tried using the `SqlDataAdapter`'s `FillSchema` method:

```
 using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter()) {
    adapter.SelectCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Mapped);
 }
```

When I inspect the `DataColumns` in the `DataTable`, I can determine if a column is an `AutoIncrement`, and can determine if it allows nulls using the `AllowDBNull` property.  However, `DefaultValue` (for columns that I know have a default value) is always `null`.

I considered:

```
DataTable schemaTable = null;
using (SqlDataReader reader = adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly)) {
   schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
   reader.Close();
}
```

but `DefaultValue` is not included in the schema.

So...how can I get a column's `DefaultValue`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this query to interrogate the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for the info you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
   TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME = 'your table name' AND
   COLUMN_NAME = 'your column name'
```

Marc

Comment: I think this implies an SQL Server (MSSQL), 2005(?) or above server, right?

Comment: No, any DB that supports the INFORMATION_SCHEMA should be supported. That's not just SQL Server - quite a few others support this as well. That's the big benefit of using INFORMATION_SCHEMA over SQL Server specific "sys.*" or "sysobjects" catalog views.

Comment: As far as I know, at least MySQL, PostgreSQL and to a degree Oracle support INFORMATION_SCHEMA (not sure about IBM DB2)

Comment: @Marc Good to know.  I always considered these metadata objects as implementation specific.   Thks.

Comment: Note that COLUMN_DEFAULT is not the actual value, but the expression to generate the default value. See my answer for more details.

Comment: You're right - but it *could* be the actual default value, if you used a fixed value like "0". That does happen at times (like for "BIT" columns). But obviuosly, expression-based defaults aren't available as actual values.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. This is because the default value can be determined at the time a record is inserted (like a `GETDATE()` or `NEW_ID()`). So the value cannot be determined in advance.

The `COLUMN_DEFAULT` column of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` gives you not the actual default value, but a string representation of the code SQL Server and the likes will execute to generate the default value. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx.

Having said that, simple constant values can easily be deduced from such an expression.