# C# DataTable.Load does not load SQL Default Values for columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, default-value

Right now we are using the following code in a large system to load the columns for a row into a datatable where we then set the values for columns we are inserting (.add).  The issue we are running into is this method does not load the columns with the SQL default values so the .add method fails because NULL is not allowed in the columns we have default values for.

Is there a way to use the below method but also have the SQL default values loaded for the columns that have them?

```
internal static DataTable FetchDataTableColumns(string tableName)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SQLHelper.CONN_STRING_NON_DTC))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SET FMTONLY ON; SELECT * FROM {0}; SET FMTONLY OFF;", tableName);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(rdr);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: defaults are not substituted because you are populating the datatable from a datareader, which does not transport any information about column defaults. IIRC, a `DataAdapter` could, let's look that up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve DataColumn.DefaultValue from a Sql Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580264/how-do-i-retrieve-datacolumn-defaultvalue-from-a-sql-table) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314483/how-to-retrieve-column-default-value-from-ms-sql-data-table, essence: column defaults can be functions and are evaluated at the time of insertion, there is currently no mechanism that could replicate this behavior in a detached data table.

Comment: So maybe I'm missing something here but this seems dumb if the default values are never loaded from SQL.  If you fill a datatable from SQL and then want to add a row to it you would never be able to unless you populated the columns that didn't allow null since the .add won't let you add the row with null values and it won't use SQL default values.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577337/cannot-insert-default-value-into-sql-database-from-win-forms-project) suggests that one possible way to go is to exclude the defaulted columns from the `SELECT` statement (a list of non-defaulting columns instead of the *) and use a `DataAdapter`. it will create itself an `INSERT` command that does not mention the defaulting columns so SQL server will substitute them when the insert is executed. This has the drawback that you can no longer provide alternative values for the defaulting columns.

Comment: if you can specify that you will only ever have to deal with constant defaults with no side effects, then use one of the approaches in the linked questions that populate the default in the datatable in a second pass from a table schema source, or hardcode them as constants in your app logic layer. if you have stuff like `GETDATE()` as defaults, you need to be aware that the timestamp may be stale if you fetch its value at the time of selection instead of insertion.